# Using Web Mercator with OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2

I am using OSM basemap in my openlayers application.

```
    var OSMlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");

    //Creating a Map
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxExtent : OSMlayer.maxExtent,
        units : OSMlayer.units,
        numZoomLevels : OSMlayer.numZoomLevels,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    });

    map.addLayers([OSMlayer]);
```

And I have a WMS service that using Web Mercator coordinates like (12.15, 88.65).

I am adding this WMS service on my map,

```
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("EcoRegions-Esri WMS", "http://myservicedomain.com/Regions/MapServer/WMSServer", {
            layers : "0",
            format : "image/png32",
            transparent : "true"                    
        }, {
            isBaseLayer : false,
            wrapDateLine : false
        });

    map.addLayers([layer]);
```

But my WMS tiles are not coming on my map. 
[image]

when I look at chrome network, I see the WMS URL bbox are like this:

```
   myservicedomain.com/Regions/MapServer/WMSServer?LAYERS=0&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng32&TRANSPARENT=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&
STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=15028131.255,-5009377.085,20037508.34,0&
WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

But `BBOX` parameter should be like this:

```
BBOX=15.255,-50.085,20.34,0
```

Comment: Those coordinates are in epsg:4326 not web mercator so the bbox request looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your map and your WMS layer are projected in Web Mercator (EPSG:900913). Therefore, it is normal that your WMS url bbox are 15028131.255,-5009377.085,20037508.34,0 instead of 15.255,-50.085,20.34,0.

So I cannot see the problem. Is your WMS working properly? What is the result of your WMS queries like:

```
  myservicedomain.com/Regions/MapServer/WMSServer?LAYERS=0&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng32&TRANSPARENT=true&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&
STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=15028131.255,-5009377.085,20037508.34,0&
WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

Tip: IMHO, It is always better to use the EPSG code EPSG:3857 instead of 900913 for the Web Mercator projection. EPSG:900913 is not an "official" EPSG code.